# Om symbol ॐ and Devanagari script

Tags: history, om

I learned the Devanagari script and couldn't help but notice the similarity of the Om symbol ॐ to the symbols of the Devanagari writing system, like अं (never mind that this is pronounced `aṃ`).

My teacher, maybe simply as pedagogical eccentricity, was *eminent* that the **Om symbol ॐ had nothing to do with the Devanagari script**. What exactly is the origin of the Om symbol and its connection with the Devanagari script, if any?

Comment: This question is not directly related to Hinduism. It is related to Sanskrit and Devanagri Transcript and method of writing.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I disagree. The nature of "om" is relevant to the practice of Hinduism.

Comment: Nature of `om` is. But its arrival in the wording isn't. He is talking about the Script here. Not the meaning!

Comment: From the [Hinduism entry on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinduism) "The syllable om (which represents the Para Brahman) and the swastika sign (which symbolises auspiciousness) have grown to represent Hinduism itself". I chose to post this question here, because I believe that I can find the best answer to my question here on Hinduism.SE.

Comment: In Devanagari it is correctly written as ओं or ओ३म्. The universal representation is ॐ. Om or Aum is a combination of three sounds a (a-kāra), u (u-kāra), m (ma-kāra). A-kara means form or shape like earth, trees, or any other object. U-kāra means formless or shapeless like water, air or fire. Ma-kāra means neither shape nor shapeless (but still exists) like the dark energy content of the Universe

Comment: Another perspective of OM is given in Bhagavad Gita 7.8, where Krishna states "[I am] the syllable om in the Vedic mantras." The precise Sanskrit is `praṇavaḥ sarva-vedeṣu`

Comment: @Prasanth, you should put that as an answer. Expect my upvote.

Comment: @VineetMenon I actually thought this was a perfect _comment_ since it didn't answer my question but added interesting information to the post.

Comment: Look at this picture.. Then you will see.. http://truthlingo.co.uk/img/sequence-of-om-devanagari.jpg

Comment: OM is Vedic sound and it doesn't need any script.

Comment: Note that he tail following the 3 is found in South Indian languages (Kannada, maybe Telugu) and is not Devanagari.

Answer (score 6):

In Devanagari it is correctly written as ओं or ओ३म्. The universal representation is ॐ. Om or Aum is a combination of three sounds a (a-kāra), u (u-kāra), m (ma-kāra). A-kara means form or shape like earth, trees, or any other object. U-kāra means formless or shapeless like water, air or fire. Ma-kāra means neither shape nor shapeless (but still exists) like the dark energy content of the Universe

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer my question. I know you initially left this as a comment and somebody suggested you post it as an answer, but in its current form I don't think this should be posted as an answer. (If you know the answer to my question, please edit it into your answer.)

Comment: ओ३म् such denotion is only advocated by Arya Samaj and definitely not a standard denotion. Also, it implies only a certain tonal way of pronouncing the mantra and does not represents the original word itself.

Answer (score 6):

Your teacher is incorrect. The symbol ॐ is indeed a Devanagari ligature of  ओ + ँ. It's actually represented slightly differently in Tibetan, Siddham, Bengali, Jain scripts to name a few.

Comment: Could you include examples of the other representations?

Comment: see here for examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om#Brahmi_script

Answer (score 3):

I post the pictures of pages referring to the link between OM and Devanagari script as described in the book 'Hidden Horizons'.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I get the PDF format of book for free online?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is available in online. I got this book at Akshardham temple, New Delhi. But you can search with it's ISBN no : 978-81-7526-331-4. Authors: Dr. David Frawley (Vamadeva Shastri) & Dr. Navaratna S. Rajaram

Answer (score 3):

Om symbol in devanagari is aum of siddham script http://www.visiblemantra.org/om.html & in devanagari om was written as a separate & special alphabet or symbol as per skanda puran shiv raghav samvaad https://youtu.be/jwlB_GDEWvw and real omkar looks like this.[image]